# Implementing a table that maintains a max heap property

Tags: mysql

For the last few days I was thinking about implementing data structures in MySQL. My idea was to create a table (or a set of tables) that allows me to implement the properties of a binary max heap. In a binary max heap, the largest node is at the top of the tree (the root node). Each insertion takes `O(N)=lg(N)` approximately. To test this theory I created the following case:

I created a table `leaderboard_2` with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE leaderboard_2 (
  _id TINYINT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  screen_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  score TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (_id) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

To maintain the heap, I created a second table `leaderboard_heap` with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE leaderboard_heap (
  _id TINYINT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  player_id TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(player_id) REFERENCES leaderboard_2(_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Every time a row is inserted into `leaderboard_2`, I run a trigger to insert a row into `leaderboard_heap` with the `_id` of the newly created row. The trigger definition is as follows:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER heap_insert
AFTER INSERT ON leaderboard_2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  DECLARE heap_len TINYINT;
  INSERT INTO leaderboard_heap VALUES (NULL, NEW._id);
  CALL check_length_heap(heap_len);

  IF heap_len > 1 THEN
  BEGIN
    DECLARE k, comp TINYINT(4);
    SET k = heap_len;
    CALL comp_row(k, FLOOR(k/2), comp);

    -- swim
    WHILE (k > 1 AND comp > 0) DO
      CALL exch_row(k, FLOOR(k/2));
      SET k = FLOOR(k/2);
      CALL comp_row(k, FLOOR(k/2), comp);
    END WHILE;
  END;
  END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

I also created the following procedures as helpers:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE check_length_heap(OUT heap_len TINYINT)
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(lh._id) INTO heap_len FROM leaderboard_heap AS lh;
END
```

The procedure above checks the current number of rows in leaderboard_heap table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE comp_row(IN row_a_id TINYINT, IN row_b_id TINYINT, OUT comp TINYINT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE rowAScore, rowBScore TINYINT;
  SELECT score INTO rowAScore FROM leaderboard_2
    WHERE _id = row_a_id;
  SELECT score INTO rowBScore FROM leaderboard_2
    WHERE _id = row_b_id;

  IF rowAScore < rowBScore THEN
    SET comp = -1;
  ELSEIF rowAScore > rowBScore THEN
    SET comp = 1;
  ELSE
    SET comp = 0;
  END IF;
END
```

Using the _id value, the scores from two players are selected from leaderboard_2 table and a comparison value is set (`OUT comp`).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE exch_row(IN row_a_id TINYINT, row_b_id TINYINT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE aPlayerId, bPlayerId TINYINT(4);

  -- make temp copy of player_id
  SELECT player_id INTO aPLayerId FROM leaderboard_heap
    WHERE _id = row_a_id;
  SELECT player_id INTO bPlayerId FROM leaderboard_heap
    WHERE _id = row_b_id;

  -- update row with id = row_a_id
  UPDATE leaderboard_heap as lh
    SET lh.player_id = bPlayerId
  WHERE lh._id = row_a_id;
  -- update row with id = row_b_id
  UPDATE leaderboard_heap as lh
    SET lh.player_id = aPlayerId
  WHERE lh._id = row_b_id;


END
```

The current row's player_id is exchanged with (swapped) the parent row where, if the _id of the current node (or, row) is `k`, then parent node (or, row) _id is `FLOOR(k/2)`. The values are swapped as long as `k != 1 AND player in current row has score greater than player in parent row`.

I used this same algorithm in both Java and JavaScript and the method works fine. In this case however, whenever there's an insert, the _id in leaderboard_heap is swapped instead of player_id.

For example, let's say we run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO leaderboard_2 VALUES ('Liu Kang', 43);
INSERT INTO leaderboard_2 VALUES ('Kung Lao', 47);
```

The leaderboard_2 table looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `leaderboard_2`
_id screen_name score   
1   Liu Kang    43  
2   Kung Lao    47  
Showing rows 0 -  1 (2 total, Query took 0.0001 seconds.)
```

After this insert, the table should look like this (if the code for heapify works as expected):

```
SELECT * FROM `leaderboard_heap` WHERE 1
_id player_id   
1   2   
2   1   
Showing rows 0 -  1 (2 total, Query took 0.0001 seconds.)
```

Instead, I get the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `leaderboard_heap` WHERE 1
_id player_id   
 2  1   
 1  2   
 Showing rows 0 -  1 (2 total, Query took 0.0001 seconds.)
```

At this point I am not sure what's happening. From my code I can see no reason why the exchange wouldn't work. I tested the exchange code in another table and there it worked as expected. Any suggestion or help will be greatly appreciated. I added all the necessary code to make the problem as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead, I get the following:

Because you have specified no `ORDER BY` clause the two table outputs you give *are* the same:

```
_id  player_id   
  1          2   
  2          1
```

and

```
_id  player_id   
  2          1   
  1          2
```

are considered exactly equivalent because what you are dealing with in SQL is sets (relational database concepts descended from a branch of mathematics called set theory) and a set is by definition unordered. If you need ordering semantics in the data you are storing then you need to include an ordering key within the data (or use a candidate ordering key that already exists in the data you are modelling with) and tell the DB to use it where needed via `ORDER BY` clauses.

The usefulness of implementing data structures like heaps, trees, and so forth in SQL tables is extremely limited (beyond academic interest, perhaps) because you are wrapping a structure in a structure that already gives you (directly, or through features like indexing) the tools you are looking for in your structure, so you are needlessly adding an extra layer of abstraction that just lives to suck away performance.

Note that this does not mean you can not *model* trees, heaps, and all their ilk, in SQL structures, of course, or store data that allows them to be persisted between instances of other parts of your application - both happen all the time. You just probably shouldn't be trying to *directly implement* them in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense since as you pointed, there are no ordering in the table defined by the query. Also, the added part of the answer explaining a downside in using "extra" abstraction layer was really helpful because I was under the impression that creating a heap would require adding some code to modify the heap table to maintain heap property. My intention was to avoid `ORDER BY` every time the highest scorers are queried. But since it degrades performance I guess I would need to find another way. Again, thanks so much for your answer.

Comment: @AbrarHossain - If you want the results in a particular order, then the only way to *guarantee* that is with `ORDER BY`, you can't reliably get around that by being clever about how you insert the data or even with indexes. If using `ORDER BY` causes performance issues, then look to improving your index strategy so the queries you need to run are better supported.